# commons-dbcp -Connection leak during XATransaction in high load

Tags: database-connection, apache-commons

We're experiencing a connection leak in a distributed transaction when the system is under heavy load. We're using commons-dbcp (latest version) + eclipselink and narayana to perform transaction coordination.

From time to time we can see a stacktrace reporting an abandoned connection. We are trying to figure out what's the root cause and we think that might be some issue in the commons dbcp (not sure) . More specifically, this parte of the code:

ManagedConnection#updateTransactionStatus

```
if (transactionContext != null) {
    if (transactionContext.isActive()) {
        if (transactionContext != transactionRegistry.getActiveTransactionContext()) {
            throw new SQLException("Connection can not be used while enlisted in another transaction");
        }
        return;
    }
    // transaction should have been cleared up by TransactionContextListener, but in
    // rare cases another lister could have registered which uses the connection before
    // our listener is called.  In that rare case, trigger the transaction complete call now
    transactionComplete();    
}
```

If we move the transactionComplete(); to an else,(see below),  the connection leak does not happen.

```
if (transactionContext != null) {
    if (transactionContext.isActive()) {
        if (transactionContext != transactionRegistry.getActiveTransactionContext()) {
            throw new SQLException("Connection can not be used while enlisted in another transaction");
        }
        return;
    }
} else {
    transactionComplete();
}
```

We have two problems here:

- Because I'm not an expert, I'm afraid of breaking something important (dbcp unit tests  still pass)
- With the change mentioned above, we get a new exeption from time to time:

  java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
          at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.toString(AtomicLong.java:313)
          at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
          at java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:4571)
          at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool$StatsStore.toString(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:1158)
          at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
          at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
          at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.toStringAppendFields(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:1328)
          at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.toStringAppendFields(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1601)
          at org.apache.commons.pool2.BaseObject.toString(BaseObject.java:31)
          at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingConnection.toString(PoolingConnection.java:536)

Can anyone with more knowledge on the commons dbcp provide some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

There was a race condition when closing the ManagedConnection which had been described in the DBCP-491. So I suggest you upgrade to the lasest common-dbcp2 which should fix this issue.